# Fragment is not replaced on gridview item click in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview

I am trying to replace or call the fragment on `GridView` item click but when I am calling my fragment, `GridView` is also visible and my fragment is also visible. I need to hide `GridView` and show my fragment.
Please help me for this. `onItemClick` of `GridView` I want to open my fragment. I have used the below code for that.

Here is my code

```
package com.softians.car;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

//================================================================================================================

    GridView grid;
    String[] web = {
            "MLA",
            "Important Work",
            "Feedback",
            "Contact",
            "Events",
            "Work Done",
            "Party Info",
            "Images",
            "Video",
            "Shere",
            "City Info",
            "Gov.Links",
            "news",
            "Educational",
            "pay Bill",
            "Election",
            "Job",
            "Mobile Bill"


    } ;
    int[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.mla,
            R.drawable.imp,
            R.drawable.feedback,

            R.drawable.contact,
            R.drawable.event,
            R.drawable.workdone,

            R.drawable.leader,
            R.drawable.images,
            R.drawable.video_player,

            R.drawable.share,
            R.drawable.cityscape,
            R.drawable.link,

            R.drawable.news,
            R.drawable.education,
            R.drawable.billpay,

            R.drawable.vote,
            R.drawable.job,
            R.drawable.transfer

    };

//========================================================================================================
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


//==========================================Grid View==========================================================================


        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
            {
//                if (position==1)
//                {
//                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Important_Activity.class);
//                    startActivity(i);
//                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//                else
//                {
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Working...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }


                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0: Information aa = new Information();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,aa);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();



//                    case 0: Intent mla = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Information.class);
//                            startActivity(mla);
//                            break;
//
//                    case 1: Intent imp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Important_Activity.class);
//                            startActivity(imp);
//                            break;
//
//                    case 3: Intent con = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Important_Activity.class);
//                            startActivity(con);
//                             break;
//
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: can you please share xml layout of activity_main?

Comment: set your fragment background to white

Answer (score 1):

You problem lies in your Fragment's `background`. Since you probably didn't define any background for the fragment it becomes transparent so both views get visible (Your GridView and Fragment).

On the root layout of your fragment XML define, for example:

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

After that, you will realize that the click events from the `View` below the fragment(GridView) are also called even if they are not visible, so in the same layout, where you defined the background of the entire Fragment, also add:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this        

 switch (position) {
             case 0: Information aa = new Information();
                  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,aa);
       fragmentTransaction.commit();
        grid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
```